# IEnumerable<T> in OCaml

Tags: f#, functional-programming, ocaml

I use F# a lot. All the basic collections in F# implement IEumberable interface, thus it is quite natural to access them using the single `Seq` module in F#. Is this possible in OCaml?

The other question is that `'a seq` in F# is lazy, e.g. I can create a sequence from `1` to `100` using `{1..100}` or more verbosely:

```
seq { for i=1 to 100 do yield i }
```

In OCaml, I find myself using the following two methods to work around with this feature:

1. generate a list:

   ```
   let rec range a b = 
     if a > b then []
     else a :: range (a+1) b;;
   ```
2. or resort to explicit recursive functions.

The first  generates extra lists. The second breaks the abstraction as I need to operate on the sequence level using higher order functions such as `map` and `fold`.

I know that the OCaml library has [Stream](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Stream.html) module. But the functionality of it seems to be quite limited, not as general as `'a seq` in F#.

BTW, I am playing Project Euler problems using OCaml recently. So there are quite a few sequences operations, that in an imperative language would be loops with a complex body.

Comment: For your second question, I think your only option is to create your own function to do that.  Though you'll want to make sure it is tail recursive though.

Answer (score 5):

This Ocaml library seems to offer what you are asking. I've not used it though.

http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/

Checkout this module, Enum
http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/doc.preview:batteries-beta1/html/api/Enum.html

I somehow feel Enum is a much better name than Seq. It eliminates the lowercase/uppercase confusion on Seqs.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I want for the second question.

Comment: Batteries Enums are the canonical solution to this problem.  OCaml's Stream module shouldn't be used unless you want to use stream parsers.  Batteries also has sequences and lazy lists, which have somewhat different implementations and semantics.

Answer (score 1):

An enumerator, seen from a functional programming angle, is exactly a `fold` function. Where a class would implement an `Enumerable` interface in an object-oriented data structures library, a type comes with a `fold` function in a functional data structure library.

`Stream` is a slightly quirky imperative lazy list (imperative in that reading an element is destructive). CamlP5 comes with a functional lazy list library, `Fstream`. [This already cited thread offers some alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631968/ocaml-lazy-lists).

Comment: I don't think `Stream` is "lazy". To me, lazy means not only on-demand but also that the result is recorded once obtained.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for something like Lazy lists.
Check out this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631968/ocaml-lazy-lists)

Answer (score 0):

The Batteries library mentioned also provides the (--) operator:

```
# 1 -- 100;;
- : int BatEnum.t = <abstr>
```

The enum is not evaluated until you traverse the items, so it provides a feature similar to your second request. Just beware that Batteries' `enum`s are mutable. Ideally, there would also be a lazy list implementation that all data structures could be converted to/from, but that work has not been done yet.